# Blog Image and Title in Right Sidebar

Tags: php, css, sidebar, blog

I am making some changes to how the blog is currently showing up in the right sidebar of a wordpress page.

- Right now there is a large image, title, excerpt, and a Read More button.
- I only want the blog section to show a little image on the left and title to the right (image mockup provided below).
- I have been able to remove the excerpt and Read More button.
- I am struggling with how the CSS needs to be created, and added to the below PHP code.

[image: image design mockup]

I'm am not the best with PHP, but I can make some updates as needed.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
                <div class="blogwrapper">

                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>

                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>

                </div>
```

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="sidebarblog customsidebar customsidewds">
<div class="blogwrapper"> 
<img width="5184" height="3456" src="https://website.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2016/01/img1000.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp- 
post-image" alt="" srcset="https://website.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2016/01/img1000.jpg 5184w, https://website.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2016/01/img1000_300x200.jpg 300w, https://website.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2016/01/img1000.jpg-768x512.jpg 768w, 
https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/img1000.jpg-1024x683.jpg 
1024w" sizes="(max-width: 5184px) 100vw, 5184px">
<h4>This is a sample blog title with text and more text</h4>   
</div>
<div class="blogwrapper"> 
<img width="1170" height="750" src="https://website.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2016/01/image1001.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp- 
post-image" alt="" srcset="https://website.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2016/01/image1001.jpg 1170w, https://website.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2016/01/image1001.jpg-300x192.jpg 300w, 
https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/image1001.jpg-768x492.jpg 
768w, https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/image1001.jpg- 
1024x656.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 1170px) 100vw, 1170px">
<h4>This is another sample blog title title with more and more text</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to put the css code inside your theme through customize theme.

> wp-admin > appearance > customize

To create a css that affects your sidebar posts like you want you need to post the html structure.

Comment: HTML structure added to original question.

Comment: Sorry! I readed the wrong way. You already have the css code. You just want to add your css code the right way correct?